# colspan="1.5" not working, any other ideas?

Tags: html

[this is what table i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydOaT.png)
I can easily get first and second row good but when i'm trying to make row third, I'm destroying row two.

I tried with width attribute and colspan but nothing work.

```html
<table border="1px" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">Cell 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td colspan="3">Cell 2</td> 
            <td colspan="3" >Cell 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Cell 4</td> 
            <td colspan="2">Cell 5</td>            
            <td colspan="2">Cell 6</td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You need to post your code so we can see what have your tried and then maybe someone can help you.

Comment: `colspan` can only have integer values. So make your table `6` cols wide. The toprow has `colspan='6'`, your middle row has `colspan='3'` and the bottom row has `colspan='2'`

Comment: I edited question with my code

Comment: Your code works as intended and creates the result which you have in your image. Where's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't look like in image look at row two. Where is end of Cell 2

Comment: It looks *exactly* like in the image! (???)

Comment: @Johannes with Chrome Win11 I'm seeing the second row as an *"uneven"* distribution of cell widths.

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/Fnt94y3/Screenshot-2022-12-24-051424.png)

Comment: @zer00ne Oh... Well, that I would simply call a bug of Chrome Windows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A `<table>` will conform to it's content by default so there's no need for each column to be equal in width. So manually assign equal column widths by assigning `table-layout: fixed` to `<table>` then an equal width for each column by either assigning each width to the `<th>` in the `<thead>` of the first `<tr>` or lacking that assign widths to the `<td>` of the first `<tr>` (of course `td` or `th` as a selector works as well), see example below.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 16.5%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">I</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">II</td>
    <td colspan="3">III</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">IV</td>
    <td colspan="2">V</td>
    <td colspan="2">VI</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```